# PHP: Why "ftp_get()" returns "true" on error?

Tags: php

`$ftp_get = ftp_get($con, $destdir . '/' . $file, $file, \FTP_BINARY);`

⇽ This function is mostly working as expected, but sometimes I got some warnings like:

`ftp_get(): Failed to open file.`

This happens only if the upload is still running and the files are not 100% uploaded, the files then has the name e.g. "foo.pdf.filepart" and not "foo.pdf". I think I have no permissions until the file is uploaded, but I am not sure.

BUT "ftp_get()" returns `true` instead of `false` while dumping the php warning that it cannot open the file. :/ Can someone find the reason for that: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c#L675

Comment: _“I think I have no permissions until the file is uploaded”_ - probably less an issue of access permissions, I would guess, and rather one of _file locking_.

Comment: You're programming in PHP, not C. That PHP and some of its modules are programmed in C is not relevant to your problem. Please don't add unrelated language tags.

Comment: As for your problem, be patient until the "upload" you mention have finished? Until the final destination is available?

Comment: Apart from the question why it returns true, is there an actual problem you need to solve here? If so, the answer probably is along the lines of “as long as the file name ends with `.filepart`, just keep your fingers off of it” …?

Comment: On a different note, namig a variable the same as the function used to set it, is going to lead to confusion in the future. Please try to make a name that's descriptive instead, like e.g. `$ftp_get_status` or similar.

Comment: What do you get when checking `error_get_last()`? Make sure you call `error_clear_last()` before your call to `ftp_get()`. Please note: the docs make no mention of any error checking, apart from the `FALSE` return value. Whether these functions will tell you anything is pure speculation.

Comment: @CBroe I don't know how other FTP client handle the upload process, what if the next FTP-Client call it ```.part``` instead of ```.filepart```. So, it's not so easy to keep the finger off of it. ;-)